How to calculate actual power consumption off of a battery through inverter
I'm sorry if this is not a bright question. If Watt = Volt x Ampere:
If I have a 12 V, 100 Ah battery that'd mean I can use 12 x 100 = 1200 watt an hour assuming I can use full 100 Ah and have a 100% efficient inverter can I use my PC at 600 W for 2 hours?
Someone on Facebook said,

an LED of 12 W at 230 V consume 0.2A and actually use 46 watt an hour.

Is that correct?
Does the voltage from inverter matter at power consumption?
Like my PC 600 W at 220 V does that mean it only use 2.7xxx amp an hour? Please, can someone explain to me.

600 W is likely the peak load of your PC, or what your Power supply is rated for. You can use tools like HWInfo (HardwareInfo, just Google it to find a link) to give you CPU and GPU package power at a given time.
Those "power draws" when you just sit at idle doing nothing are going to be very low, less than 100 W combined. However, heavy gaming loads are going to raise them up to higher levels, potentially 200  -300 W. It is very unlikely unless you spent 1000$ each on CPU and GPU that you are going to get anywhere near 600 W of real PC usage.
Once you have HWinfo or some similar tool that can check power draw, you can get a rough idea of how much power you ACTUALLY use for a given period of time. That is your real power usage you can apply to your inverter using the math you listed in your equation. If you do idle computing for 2 hours and draw an average of 100W and do 2 hours of gaming that draws 200 W, you will have used about 600WH of energy (200 × 2 + 100 × 2).
IDK what that Facebook statement is all about, but don't listen to them as it doesn't apply here, and is likely wrong as most stuff on Facebook is...

The Facebook quote seems like outright nonsense or at least missing a large amount of context.

Just to answer the Facebook statement:

LED of 12 W at 230 V consume 0.2A and actually use 46 watt an hour.

No.

It means that it would consume 46 W while it is switched on. That's the power consumption.
If run for one hour it means that it would consume 46 W × 1 h = 46 Wh. That's the energy consumption That's what your electricity meter measures and what you pay for.

Energy is power × time. It's not power / time which is what "watts per hour" would be..

He said 20 of 12w led would only last 1 hr off of 12v 100ah if I were to use 80% of the battery. Somehow, he's a management engineer at a electrical engineering service company.

@greybeard - er - there is some confusion there. I assume you mean 1.2kWh = 4.32 MJ. (MegaJoules). It is also equal to about 1032 Calories.

Along the same line, 12 V, 100 Ah ≠ 12 × 100 = 1200 watt an hour - the unit is Wh, 1 Wh = 3.6 kWs = 3.6 kJ. 1.2 kWh = 4.32 MJ, about half the daily energy metabolised by an adult human.

"He said 20 of 12w led would only last 1 hr off of 12v 100ah ..." (1) Terminology: 'V' for volt, 'A' for ampere and 'W' for watt. (Capitals matter.) (2) Lamps: 20 x 12 = 240 W. (3) Battery capacity: 12 V x 100 Ah = 1200 Wh. (4) Runtime to 200 Wh remaining: $ t = \frac E P = \frac {1200 - 200} {240} = 4 \ \text {h approx} $.
